# Checking if a model contains an ID in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have something like this:

```
$item = Item::all();
```

And something like this:

```
$shop->items(); //Return a list of item
```

Now I want to check in blade if the shop has the item (example):

```
@foreach($items as $item)
<input type="checkbox" @if($shop->hasItem()) checked @endif>
```

Is there an easy way to do this? I could do another `@foreach(shop->items)` and check if `$item->id` is in there but I feel there must be a clean way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of many options is to query the relation:

```
@if($shop->items->where('id', $item->id)->count()) checked @endif
```